# Pass linux kernel option through VMware

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, vmware

Maybe my question is quite strange, but it bothers me for some time and I can't find the answer by myself. Actually the question itself is in the subject but let me introduce you into the situation.

We have a kind of system, that is based on VMware VM with SLES inside. System is installed from DVD image almost automatically using Autoyast. Almost - because I have to specify location of Autoyast xml config manually as a kernel option to system installer. I'd like to eliminate this step and pass this option automatically.

I can see 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. Extract ISO content and modify bootloader config to pass this option and build ISO back again
2. Extract kernel and initrd from ISO and use DHCP/TFTP/PXE to organise a network boot with arbitrary options

Neither of them doesn't satisfy me. I'd like to do this without manipulations with ISO image to make this trick compatible with any version of SLES or image. In my opinion it could be achieved only by means of VMware. But I couldn't find anything appropriate in Google.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Maybe your VMware is using some Linux loader (like `grub`) first (very few are booting Linux without any loader). Then you can configure that boot loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can have a floppy disc image containing a loader (e.g. syslinux) which you can programmatically create, then use the DVD image for the rest of the install (including kernel if you use isolinux?)

Comment: yes, we are already using additional ISO mounted into second virtual disk drive, which we can modify without problems. I think that installing some loader onto this ISO would do the best in my case

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need have a simple bootloader like [extlinux](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/EXTLINUX) to edit the boot command line, which you can parse and use on your system as `/proc/cmdline`.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack, change and repack an ISO using `mkisofs`. It's distributed with in most distributions' `cdrtools` package.

Answer (score 0):

VMware has the VMCI API — given enough brainpower, you could augment your bootloader to use it and get a Xen-like "extraargs=" (keyword in a /etc/xen/vm/xxx config file) functionality. (In Xen that works because the HV can start certain kernels directly, without having a "black box" machine that emulates a BIOS or a traditional boot etc.)